# How to count number of columns and rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where i need to count number of columns, number of rows, and size of each table for a given database.

The query below is not giving the exact result,

```
SELECT t1.table_name, t1. table_rows,COUNT(t2.table_name) AS table_colums, t1. data_length 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1 
JOIN (SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema='my_db_name') t2 
ON t1.table_name=t2.table_name 
WHERE t1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_name';
```

Any clues?

Comment: @Martin i am not using PHP

Answer (score 2):

Counting rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable;
```

Counting columns:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'yourtable'
```

If you mean by *size of each table* the size in MB, then:

```
SELECT 
    table_name AS `Table`, 
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "yourdatabase"
    AND table_name = "yourtable";
```

Comment: thank you for quick response, unfortunately i don't know the table name because i need to display list of table with the rows, columns,size of a database.

Comment: are those `$` PHP variables? OP may not be using PHP. Good answer re: size

Comment: @sridharnetha Play around with the WHERE clause to restrict or generalize the output to your needs and combine the three queries to one if you can/need. Depending on your case you may use UNION. Your flexibility also depends on your performance requirements.

Comment: @Martin Removed the *confusing* dollar signs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This query solved my problem.

```
SELECT t1.table_name, t1.table_rows, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'my_db_name'
AND table_name = t1.table_name) AS colsm, 
t1.data_length
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1
WHERE t1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you the required result

```
SELECT t1.table_name
,round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
,(select count(*) from information_schema.columns c where c.table_schema = t1.table_schema and c.table_name = t1.table_name) as cols
,t1.table_rows as rows
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1 
WHERE t1.table_schema = 'my_db_name'
```